# How to combine regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement where input string should not be an empty string  (all characters allowed) and length should be in between 1 to 500.

I found working expressions for separately, one for checking empty string and one for length. I'm unable to club them to result an expression which should tell me if input is 'Empty string' or more than 500 chars.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ranadheemachineni/LZf7H/5871/)

for empty string

```
var regex = /^\s*$/;
```

for length

```
{1,499}
```

Comment: *"jsfiddle here"*  The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Shouldn't be an empty string and length is between 0 and 500? there is a contradiction there. Perhaps you meant [1 , 499]

Comment: yes Mr geek. updated the description

Comment: Is a 500-character string allowed or not?

Comment: 500 character string is allowed. if string is more than 500 characters its not allowed

Answer (score 3):

From your example checking for an "empty" string, it's clear you want to ignore whitespace at the beginning or end.

The simplest way to do this, if you don't actually have a regex requirement, is just `trim` and check the length:

```
str = str.trim();
if (str.length && str.length <= 500) {
    // All good
}
```

But if you *need* a regex (perhaps an HTML5 validation regex), then it's simply a matter of saying 1. "ignore whitespace at the beginning, 2. require 1-500 characters in the middle, and 3. ignore whitespace at the end." (with anchors to ensure we're matching the full string):

```
//          111          333
// ---------vvv----------vvv
var rex = /^\s*\S.{0,499}\s*$/;
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^
//             2222222222
```

Note the `\S` which requires at least one non-whitespace character there, followed by 0 to 499 other characters.

**Note:** You'll need to `trim` the string at some point, though, since the whitespace at one end of the other can take you over the 500 limit.

Example usage:

```js
// NOTE: Using 5 instead of 500 to make tests shorter
var rex = /^\s*\S.{0,4}\s*$/;
console.log(rex.test("")); // false
console.log(rex.test("a")); // true
console.log(rex.test(" a ")); // true
console.log(rex.test(" 12345 ")); // true
console.log(rex.test(" 123456 ")); // false
console.log(rex.test("123456")); // false
console.log(rex.test("1234       ")); // true
console.log(rex.test("       ")); // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

**Note:** In JavaScript, `.` doesn't match line termination characters. If you want to allow those, use `[\w\W]` (anything that's a word character or not a word character) instead of `.`: `/^\s*[\w\W]{1,500}\s*$/`

Comment: @user2555212 However, this will match strings that have more than 500 chars. Your requirement is *length should be in between 1 to 500*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I interpreted it as "1-500 characters ignoring whitespace at either end" (as I said at the beginning).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The first paragraph is quite clear: *input string should not be an empty string (all characters allowed) and length should be in between 1 to 500*. Your solution is not meeting the second requirement. Otherwise, the question is not clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: See the regex for "empty string" (which, again, I called out in my first sentence).

Comment: @user2555212: To be clear: The string could have more than 500 chars if there's whitespace on either end (in fact, one of the tests above shows that); you'd presumably trim if you want to remove those.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Even if you are right about the number of chars, and there can be more than 500 all in all, the `^\s*.{1,500}\s*$` regex can match a blank string that OP seems to avoid matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Very good point, I kinda missed that out in my list of tests, didn't I? Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @user2555212: Note fix above.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a bit over the top for your needs. What's wrong with...

```
if (myString == null || myString.length > 500){
    // handle failed validation here
}
```

**EDIT**

Above will allow empty string to pass. For between 1 and 500 use

```
if (myString == null || myString.length < 1 || myString.length > 500){
    // handle failed validation here
}
```

Comment: `'' == null // false`

Comment: I agree with you.  its doable with above if condition

Comment: @evolutionxbox OP asked for between 0 and 500, I assume an empty string is valid.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted? _"input string should not be an empty string"_

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ah, OP has updated question to state explicitly between 1 and 500. Think we both read the question a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/^(?!\s+$)[\s\S]{1,500}$/
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s+$)` - no 1 or more whitespaces up to the end of string (a string that consists of 1 or more whitespaces is failed here)
- `[\s\S]{1,500}`  - any 1 to 500 chars (so, no empty string is allowed)
- `$` - end of string.

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference between `/[\s\S]/` and `/./`?

Comment: @Zevgon `.` does not match line break chars.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thanks @Wiktor